# Tuning async with aiohttp.ClientSession and await session.request

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

I need help figure out what I did wrong and guidance to debug issues.

The program keep throwing one of these 3 errors.   I'm using python 3.6 on window 10.
The error starts with crawling only 200 urls and I need to verify up to 20000 urls

1. OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
2. aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerTimeoutError: Timeout on reading data from socket

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_asyncio.py", line 91, in <module>
    def func():
  File "E:\git\AzureRepo\SharePoint\applitools\timer.py", line 8, in wrapper
    runs = timeit.repeat(func, number=number,
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\timeit.py", line 238, in repeat
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).repeat(repeat, number)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\timeit.py", line 205, in repeat
    t = self.timeit(number)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\timeit.py", line 177, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
  File "test_asyncio.py", line 110, in func
    res = loop.run_until_complete(du_main(all_urls, all_site))
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "test_asyncio.py", line 82, in du_main
    result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "test_asyncio.py", line 43, in du_fetch
    async with session.get(url=url, allow_redirects=False,
  File "E:\git\AzureRepo\SharePoint\applitools\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "E:\git\AzureRepo\SharePoint\applitools\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 544, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "E:\git\AzureRepo\SharePoint\applitools\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 890, in start
    message, payload = await self._protocol.read()  # type: ignore
  File "E:\git\AzureRepo\SharePoint\applitools\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 604, in read
    await self._waiter
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerTimeoutError: Timeout on reading data from socket
```

3. ERROR - Unclosed connection

```
async def du_fetch(session, site, url):

    # try:
    t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
    async with session.get(url=url, allow_redirects=False,
                           timeout=ClientTimeout(total=1200,  # 1200 works
                                                 sock_connect=5,  # 600 works
                                                 sock_read=5)) as resp:
        redirect_url = resp.headers.get('Location', None)
        t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
        time_diff = round((t1 - t0).total_seconds(), 3)
        # resp.close()
        # logging.debug(f'du_fetch {site} {url.encode("utf-8")}')
    '''
    except Exception as e:
        t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
        time_diff = round((t1 - t0).total_seconds(), 3)

        logging.debug(e)

        return (site, 999,
                t0, time_diff, url, e.__class__.__name__)
    '''
    return (site, resp.status,
            t0, time_diff, url, redirect_url)


async def du_main(urls, sites):
    client_timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(
        total=120)  # total 300 seconds (5min) timeout # 12000 works
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100,  # default is 100 # 600 works
                                     # limit_per_host=0,
                                     ssl=False)
    dummy_jar = aiohttp.DummyCookieJar()
    tasks = []

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector,
                                     timeout=client_timeout,
                                     cookie_jar=dummy_jar) as session:
        tasks = [du_fetch(session, sites[i], url)
                 for i, url in enumerate(urls)]
        result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        logging.error(f'du_main {session}')
        await session.close()
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    res = loop.run_until_complete(du_main(all_urls, all_site))
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Could you include the full traceback for the error?

Comment: @PirateNinjas I updated the post with full traceback.  I tried a variety of parameters value.  Timeout, sock_connect, sock_read.  It seems better with 16000 requests, I'm down to about 100 ServerTimeoutError errors.  But I still don't understand and how to tune it.    Right now, I increase the value to really high number.

Comment: it may be that your timeout is insufficient. At the moment, it appears you set a timeout for the session (i.e. shared across all requests). It may be better to set a timeout at the individual request level instead

Comment: Individual timeout didn't work.  I have the same problem with this thread. 
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3203

Comment: One of the suggestions there is to use semaphores to delay adding the tasks to the event loop. Have you tried that? I can knock together an example if that would be helpful

Comment: That is too advance for me.  an example is appreciated!

Comment: I want to try to use semaphone.  Is that how you limit concurrency with asyncio?  Currently, I create buckets and making request based on the number of buckets.  I think that will create several sessions.  Is that bad?